# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.sets' has no attribute 'set_intersection'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, coco

Even though I tried, I couldn't solve this mistake.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSDbfGsxruA

I almost got to the last step when I added The Mask RCNN, but I'm stuck here.

### **Error Log**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-138183a2a830> in <module>
      1 # Create model object in inference mode.
----> 2 model = modellib.MaskRCNN(mode="inference", model_dir=MODEL_DIR, config=config)
      3 
      4 # Load weights trained on MS-COCO
      5 model.load_weights(COCO_MODEL_PATH, by_name=True)

~\**\Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\model.py in __init__(self, mode, config, model_dir)
   1838         self.model_dir = model_dir
   1839         self.set_log_dir()
-> 1840         self.keras_model = self.build(mode=mode, config=config)
   1841 
   1842     def build(self, mode, config):

~\**\Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\model.py in build(self, mode, config)
   2044             # output is [batch, num_detections, (y1, x1, y2, x2, class_id, score)] in
   2045             # normalized coordinates
-> 2046             detections = DetectionLayer(config, name="mrcnn_detection")(
   2047                 [rpn_rois, mrcnn_class, mrcnn_bbox, input_image_meta])
   2048 

**\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    949     # >> model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    950     if _in_functional_construction_mode(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list):
--> 951       return self._functional_construction_call(inputs, args, kwargs,
    952                                                 input_list)
    953 

**\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _functional_construction_call(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_list)
   1088           layer=self, inputs=inputs, build_graph=True, training=training_value):
   1089         # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
-> 1090         outputs = self._keras_tensor_symbolic_call(
   1091             inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
   1092 

**\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call(self, inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
    820       return nest.map_structure(keras_tensor.KerasTensor, output_signature)
    821     else:
--> 822       return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    823 
    824   def _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks):

**\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py in _infer_output_signature(self, inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
    861           # TODO(kaftan): do we maybe_build here, or have we already done it?
    862           self._maybe_build(inputs)
--> 863           outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    864 
    865         self._handle_activity_regularization(inputs, outputs)

**\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    668       except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    669         if hasattr(e, 'ag_error_metadata'):
--> 670           raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    671         else:
    672           raise
```

AttributeError: in user code:

```
**\Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\model.py:810 call  *
    detections_batch = utils.batch_slice(
**\Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\utils.py:820 batch_slice  *
    output_slice = graph_fn(*inputs_slice)
**\Mask_RCNN\mrcnn\model.py:720 refine_detections_graph  *
    keep = tf.sets.set_intersection(tf.expand_dims(keep, 0),

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow._api.v2.sets' has no attribute 'set_intersection'
```

**model.py** arranged according to here.

https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1070#issuecomment-740430758

Comment: This might be related to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43982

Answer (score 1):

As per the solution provided by SalahRahimi on [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43982#issuecomment-713403271) regarding the same issue, the user was able to resolve the issue by doing the following changes.

> The main issue here was the tensor flow version. `mrcnn` doesn't work
> with tensorflow.2.0, therefore I had to remove this version and
> re-install version 1.15. Note that it is not possible to install
> version 1.15 in Python3.8, so I switched to Python 3.7, which allowed
> me to install tensorflow 1.15. Now, this problem is resolved and I
> have been able to run the programme.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by making the following substitutions, described in this link:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43982.

```
"tf.sets.set_intersection(...)
```

to:

```
tf.compat.v1.sets.set_intersection(...)
```

and:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

to:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
```